# How to retrive the information of BLEs which are connected to a BLE

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm new to Core Bluetooth. Using custom GATT my BLE device will exchange the information with other BLE devices, What I have to do is collect the information that my BLE device got and need to send it to cloud and after that need to clear that data.

I mostly saw Central Manager(Phone) and Peripheral(BLE device) examples but not sure how to get the connected BLE devices information. Do I need to use CBPeripheralManager? Please suggest the approach to handle it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the context? What will the role of the iPhone be? Will it be responsible to forward the data to the cloud service? Do you have a given sensor device with BLE connectivity? Can you change the software on the device? If not, what GATT services and characteristics does it implement?

Comment: And BTW: Your use of the term "BLE" is rather strange. You seem to use it as an equivalent of "device".

Comment: @Krish Have a look through this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor)